# How to remove dataframe values that are not present in the list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
myList = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']
```

my.csv

```
items    quantity 
item1        1
item2        2
item3        2
item4        4
item4        1
item5        1
item6        3
```

I need to remove all the dataframe rows that don't contain the list value in items column.

desired output:

```
items    quantity 
item1        1
item2        2
item3        2
item4        4
item4        1
item5        1
```

Could someone be able to help me with this? thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you want something like `df[df['items'].isin(myList)]`. Untested.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work.

Comment: I m not sure about the goals but pd.read_csv(skiprows = lambda x:x in [1, 2, 4, 6]) can be used too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.iterrows()` function where df is an abbreviation for `pandas.DataFrame` :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myList = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5']

df = pd.DataFrame({  "items": ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item4','item5','item6'], "quantity": [1,2,2,4,1,1,3] })


for i, r in df.iterrows():
    for j in myList:
        if j==r['items']:
            print(j," ",r['quantity'])



item1   1
item2   2
item3   2
item4   4
item4   1
item5   1
```